# Scan through all integers within a range by incrementing constant amount

Tags: number-theory

Given a natural number $k$, what is a way to find out all natural number $i$ such that, when we start with $n = 0$ and keep adding $i$ to $n$, the value $n \mod k$ traverses through all numbers between $0$ and $k - 1$ (inclusive) before hitting any of them twice?

For example, when $k = 360$, then $i = 19$ (a divisor of $361$) is one possibility because, starting with $n = 0$, sequential addition of $i$ to $n$ gives the sequence:

$$0, 19, 38, ..., 323, 342, 361, 380, ...$$

where we take $n \mod k$, it would be:

$$0, 19, 38, ..., 323, 342, 1, 20, ...$$

and would scan through all numbers from $0$ to $359$ before hitting the same number twice.

A trivial example for any $k$ is $i = 1$.

Comment: It depends on gcd$(i, k)$. Well basically situation you want happens precisely when their only common factor is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen exactly for all i such that gcd(i, k) = 1. Here is why:

Suppose gcd(i, k) is not 1. Then there does not exist a, b such that ai + bk = 1. So there does not exist any a such that ai = 1 mod k,

On the other hand, suppose gcd(i, k) = 1. Then there exists a, b such that ai + bk = 1.

ai = 1 (mod k).
So 2ai = 2 (mod k)

...

jai = j (mod k)

We can also prove that we traverse through all numbers before hitting any of them twice:

Suppose bi = ci (mod k).

Then (b-c)i is divisible by k.
But i is coprime with k.
So k must divide (b-c). In other words, there must be at least (k-1) numbers between bi and ci in this traversal. By a similar argument, none of these k-1 numbers may be repeated either.

Answer (score 1):

It works for any $i$ such that $\gcd (i,k)=1$.  If the $\gcd$ is not $1$, after $\frac k{\gcd (i,k)}$ additions you will be back where you started.